# What flutter package can make this calendar widget like for an agenda?

Tags: flutter

[agenda's calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZAhw.png)

Hi guys ! How can i make this calendar field for agenda with flutter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use
syncfusion_flutter_calendar package